# Where are all the secret areas in Minion Rush?

Tags: despicable-me-minion-rush

I need to find all the secret areas in Despicable 2 Minion Rush.

I've already found `Disco` area in `Gru's lab`.

I need help in finding the secret area in `Residential` and `El Macho's Liar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no secret areas in the Residential area or El Macho's Lair.  There is also no secret area at [the Beach](http://despicableme.wikia.com/wiki/Minion_Beach_%28Minion_Rush%29).

There are a few other special areas, though since you run straight into them I'm not sure they are considered *secrets*.  THose would be the [Bank of Evil](http://youtu.be/Z2agRp5qRn0) in the [Downtown area](http://despicableme.wikia.com/wiki/Downtown_%28Minion_Rush%29) and the [Movie Theater](http://youtu.be/0CtgXSEgnJA) in [the Mall](http://despicableme.wikia.com/wiki/Paradise_Mall_%28Minion_Rush%29)

Answer (score 1):

You don't find the secret areas for Residential and El Macho's Lair, you just gotta keep running until they are generated.